# How to run the sftp command with a password from Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, sftp

I need to transfer a log file to a remote host using [sftp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_file_transfer_program) from a Linux host. I have been provided credentials for the same from my operations group. However, since I don't have control over other host, I cannot generate and share RSA keys with the other host.

So is there a way to run the `sftp` command (with the username/password provided) from inside the Bash script through a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job?

I found a similar Stack Overflow question, *[Specify password to sftp in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268865)*, but there was no satisfactory answer to my problem.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

You have a few options other than using public key authentication:

1. Use [keychain](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-passwordless-login-with-keychain-for-scripts/)
2. Use [sshpass](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/) (less secured but probably that meets your requirement)
3. Use [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) (least secured and more coding needed)

If you decide to give sshpass a chance here is a working script snippet to do so:

```
export SSHPASS=your-password-here
sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - sftp-user@remote-host << !
   cd incoming
   put your-log-file.log
   bye
!
```

Comment: For using it on Mac: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102557/sftp-command-in-bash-script-with-mac-os-x/9102723#9102723

Comment: Hi, I have similar problem, and I tried to use `expect` as other alternatives are not present on the host. With `expect` I am getting this error.. `Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
`. Please can you let me know, how to connect to a sftp host with passwd from a bash script.

Comment: Please see, have asked the question here.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12508206/1135954

Comment: No need to export, I think. `SSHPASS=password sshpass -e ...` should do.

Comment: @Jens: Agreed that export is not really required here.

Comment: I was able to do a one-liner to dowload a log file: `sshpass -p "my_password" sftp -oPort=9999 user@host:dir/file.log`

Comment: @gorus: One-liner is very cool however I didn't want to use password on command line because of enhanced snooping risks.

Comment: @Dru: Yes `export SSHPASS=your-password-here` goes into env of that user but how will `ps -ef` reveal env of a different user?

Comment: `-oBatchMode=no` was the crucial missing piece for me.

Comment: What did you use and what didn't work. Feel free to create a new question since this is very old thread.

Comment: Hi Anubhava - Here is my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540156/automating-sftp-using-ibm-aixunix-shell-script

Comment: I am working on IBM AIX and trying to get a file from remote server using sftp command...

Comment: Hi Anubhava - Can you help me out regarding this script... I tried using except but it doesn't work. Here is my code I have written at below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540156/automating-sftp-using-ibm-aixunix-shell-script

Comment: Hi Anubhava - Any luck?

Comment: Hi Anubhava - I tried all the three options but none of them worked for me....Can you please help me out... thank you...

Comment: What error did you get while trying `sshpass` command? I use it every day on my system.

Comment: I don't have root user on that machine to install new software. I am looking for a way to do it without installing new software

Comment: I have installed it without root access but discussing that will be diverging too much from this question.

Comment: Hi, sshpass is a great idea, thanks, works fine! But now, I get a mail with all SFTP-commands in the here script area every time this is run via crontab. So does anyone know how to suppress this output to the console?

Comment: You can add `> ~/file.out 2>&1` to redirect the output and stderr to a file.

Comment: @anubhava very thanks for this answer. I used it with my bash script file that is start via crontab -e. I change the exclamation point "!"  to "EOF" because crontab doens't recognied this character in script

Comment: May I ask what exactly does the ! do?

Comment: `!` can be any marker string. You can use `EOF` or `EOD` as well.

Comment: Hey, how can I use that in order to transfer a folder? ```put -r source target```?

Comment: You can zip the folder and transfer zip file for faster transfer or else use `scp`

Comment: `keychain` won't allow you to go with a password (the specific topic of this question), but facilitates public key authentication (with a passphrase on SSH a private key), right?

Answer (score 136):

Another way would be to use lftp:

```
lftp sftp://user:password@host  -e "put local-file.name; bye"
```

The disadvantage of this method is that other users on the computer can read the password from tools like `ps` and that the password can become part of your shell history.

A more secure alternative which is available since LFTP 4.5.0 is setting the `LFTP_PASSWORD` environment variable and executing lftp with `--env-password`. Here's a full example:

```
export LFTP_PASSWORD="just_an_example"
lftp --env-password sftp://user@host  -e "put local-file.name; bye"

# Destroy password after use
export LFTP_PASSWORD=""
```

LFTP also includes a cool mirroring feature (can include delete after confirmed transfer `--Remove-source-files`):

```
lftp -e 'mirror -R /local/log/path/ /remote/path/' --env-password -u user sftp.foo.com
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting an alternative but can we avoid supplying password on command line?

Comment: Downvoted for showing the password to anyone on the same computer

Comment: You can create the script file for lftp, this way you will not have to provide the password in the command line.

Create a file `put-script`: `open sftp://user:password@host; put local-file.name; exit`

Than run `lftp -f put-script`

This way you do not have to have the username and password in a command line and can set up restrictive permissions to your script file.

Comment: @obaranovsky That is a good idea. I wonder if I were to add this to my environment variable as alias or a function, would it be secure and possible to hide it from other users?

Comment: Far easier to do `lftp` than mess around with `sftp` and `sshpass`. Good answer.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Upvoted because it is exactly what the OP asked for - "a way to run the sftp command (**with** the username / **password provided**) from inside the Bash script".

Comment: Just a note, it only ran for us on Solaris if we used: *export LFTP_PASSWORD=${our_password}*, would not work without the export clause.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I've changed the script to reflect your thoughts. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I've forgotten how often I used to use lftp [every day] and this answer completely solved an issue a client had.

Also respects here docs for commands.

$ lftp sftp://user@example.com << EOF
ls
cd foo
get bar
EOF

Comment: How do I transfer a folder with this? In the line ```"put local-file.name; bye"``` the destination path seems to be missing.

Answer (score 68):

`EXPECT` is a great program to use.

On Ubuntu install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install expect
```

On a CentOS Machine install it with:

```
yum install expect
```

Lets say you want to make a connection to  a sftp server and then upload a local file from your local machine to the remote sftp server

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn sftp username@hostname.com
expect "password:"
send "yourpasswordhere\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd logdirectory\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "put /var/log/file.log\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
interact
```

This opens a sftp connection with your password to the server.

Then it goes to the directory where you want to upload your file, in this case "logdirectory"

This uploads a log file from the  local directory found at /var/log/ with the files name being file.log to the "logdirectory" on the remote server

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had expect as one of my options for achieving this task.

Comment: Thank you. I found your answer through a search, used it and built a script successfully with expect. Just posted the script for poterity

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, I have already upvoted it :)

Comment: I'm using this to enter the passphrase for ssh private key. It is handier to put same public key on all servers and just rotate the private key passphrase periodically.

Comment: I get - `spawn: command not found`

Comment: For that issue, use the solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26874001/1402304

Answer (score 30):

You can use lftp interactively in a shell script so the password not saved in .bash_history or similar by doing the following:

```
vi test_script.sh
```

Add the following to your file:

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST=<yourhostname>
USER=<someusername>
PASSWD=<yourpasswd>

cd <base directory for your put file>

lftp<<END_SCRIPT
open sftp://$HOST
user $USER $PASSWD
put local-file.name
bye
END_SCRIPT
```

And write/quit the vi editor after you edit the host, user, pass, and directory for your put file typing `:wq` .Then make your script executable `chmod +x test_script.sh` and execute it `./test_script.sh`.

Comment: To overwrite existing file, add "set xfer:clobber on" after lftp<<END_SCRIPT

Answer (score 19):

I was recently asked to switch over from ftp to sftp, in order to secure the file transmission between servers. We are using Tectia SSH package, which has an option `--password` to pass the password on the command line.

example : `sftp --password="password" "userid"@"servername"`

Batch example :

```
(
  echo "
  ascii
  cd pub
  lcd dir_name
  put filename
  close
  quit
    "
) | sftp --password="password" "userid"@"servername"
```

I thought I should share this information, since I was looking at various websites, before running the help command (`sftp -h`), and was i surprised to see the password option.

Comment: +1 for you good suggestion. However this will require you to pass the password on command line and anybody on the system doing `ps` command would be able to see your password.

Comment: I tried that, I got `unknown option -- -
usage: sftp [-1246aCfpqrv] [-B buffer_size] [-b batchfile] [-c cipher]
          [-D sftp_server_path] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit]
          [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-R num_requests] [-S program]
          [-s subsystem | sftp_server] host
       sftp [user@]host[:file ...]
       sftp [user@]host[:dir[/]]
       sftp -b batchfile [user@]host`

Comment: @ihue probably because you need **Techia SSH**, not OpenSSH

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work with openssh, not a good solution.

Answer (score 18):

You can override by enabling Password less authentication. But you should install keys (pub, priv) before going for that.

Execute the following commands at local server.

```
Local $> ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Press ENTER for all options prompted. No values need to be typed.

```
Local $> cd .ssh
Local $> scp .ssh/id_rsa.pub user@targetmachine:
Prompts for pwd$>  ENTERPASSWORD
```

Connect to remote server using the following command

```
Local $> ssh user@targetmachine
Prompts for pwd$> ENTERPASSWORD
```

Execute the following commands at remote server

```
Remote $> mkdir .ssh
Remote $> chmod 700 .ssh
Remote $> cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
Remote $> chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
Remote $> exit
```

Execute the following command at local server to test password-less authentication.
It should be connected without password.

```
$> ssh user@targetmachine
```

Comment: +1 for your answer but question was about doing it without public/private keys.

Comment: oops.. Just saw the restrictions on key sharing :)

Comment: Out of curiosity will this command `lftp -p ${port} -u ${login_id},${password} ${ip_number}` when invoked from a shell script print them some where? How did you solve apart from sshpass?

Comment: I don't have `lftp` and rely on `sshpass` from Mac and Linux both.

Comment: Pure gold. Thanks! :)

Comment: Tip: If you are setting this up for additional remote servers,  copy the same id_rsa.pub to the remote servers.  The public key id_rsa.pub is generated once on the local server and shared with all remote hosts with which password less authentication needs to be set up.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way I found to accomplish this, without installing any third-party library like **Expect**, **SSHPASS**...etc, is by using a combination of **CURL**, and **SFTP**. Those two are almost in every Linux machine.

This is the command you should execute, after changing the values.

```
curl  -k "sftp://SERVER_IP:SERVER_PORT/FULL_PATH_OF_THE_FILE" --user "SERVER_USER:SERVER_PASSOWRD" -o "THE_NAME_OF_THE_FILE_AFTER_DOWNLOADING_IT"
```

***Example:***

```
curl  -k "sftp://10.10.10.10:77/home/admin/test.txt" --user "admin:123456" -o "test.txt"
```

***Explanation:***

We are connecting to the server **10.10.10.10:77** using the username **admin** and password **123456**, to move the file **/home/admin/test.txt** from that server to the server you are using currently to execute the above command.

Comment: isn't this the opposite direction? this shows how to copy a file from the remote server to the local, when the question is to upload from local to remote.

Comment: Very clever solution that I've never seen before... no dependencies.

Comment: Showing error: "sftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Comment: This makes me think of how simple it would be to add to my `.bashrc`

Answer (score 8):

Combine sshpass with a locked-down credentials file and, in practice, it's as secure as anything - if you've got root on the box to read the credentials file, all bets are off anyway.

Answer (score 7):

**Bash program to wait for sftp to ask for a password then send it along:**

```
#!/bin/bash
expect -c "
spawn sftp username@your_host
expect \"Password\"
send \"your_password_here\r\"
interact "
```

You may need to install expect, change the wording of 'Password' to lowercase 'p' to match what your prompt receives. The problems here is that it exposes your password in plain text in the file as well as in the command history. Which nearly defeats the purpose of having a password in the first place.

Comment: +1 but I think you state it clearly what the problems are with this approach.

Answer (score 5):

You can use sshpass for it. Below are the steps

1. Install sshpass     For Ubuntu - `sudo apt-get install sshpass`
2. Add the Remote IP to your known-host file if it is first time
   For Ubuntu  -> ssh user@IP -> enter 'yes'
3. give a combined command of scp and sshpass for it.
   Below is a sample code for war coping to remote tomcat
   `sshpass -p '#Password_For_remote_machine' scp /home/ubuntu/latest_build/abc.war #user@#RemoteIP:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`

Answer (score 2):

A few people have mentioned `sshpass` but not many clear coding examples...

This is how we are doing it with bash scripts for rsync backups:

```
sshpass -p "${RSYNC_PASSWORD}" sftp "${RSYNC_USER}"@"${RSYNC_REMOTE_HOST}"
```

Keep in mind you will have to `sudo apt install sshpass` before this works properly.

Comment: Clear (and better) example is given by the very first (most-upvoted) answer by @anubhava.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl His answer uses `export` and several other flags that are not required and in fact not even a good idea to use...

Comment: If you believe that using `-p` is better than `SSHPASS` (I do not agree), please explain why in  your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl --netrc-file NETRC --upload-file LOCALPATH sftp://HOST:PORT/REMOTEPATH
```

LOCALPATH may be `-` for stdin. The NETRC file has lines with format:

```
machine HOST login USERNAME password PASSWORD
```

(It's also possible to use `--user USER:PASSWORD` instead of `--netrc-file` but that reveals the password to anyone running `ps` locally at the same time, so don't do that.)

If the NETRC file does not exist permanently, your script can create a temporary file (possibly with the help of `mktemp`).

Thanks to @ASammour for pointing out that curl speaks SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Python script with scp and os library to make a system call.

1. ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 (local machine)
2. ssh-copy-id user@remote_server_address
3. create a Python script like:

```
    import os
    cmd = 'scp user@remote_server_address:remote_file_path local_file_path'
    os.system(cmd)
```

4. create a rule in crontab to automate your script
5. done

Comment: The question is about using a password authentication, not a public key authentication.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but can be useful for other ones looking for alternatives for their problems. Because the issue is related.

Answer (score 0):

[@ASamour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68370320/188963) inspired me to put this in my .bashrc:

```bash
sshpass()
{
        server=$1
        file=$2
        userpass=$3
        outfile=${4:-$file}

        curl \
                --insecure sftp://${server}/${file} \
                --user "${userpass}" \
                --output ${outfile}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need —insecure option?

Comment: I have no idea. I just expanded the `-k` switch that @ASamour used.

Answer (score -1):

I came here only to get the auth trick, and then run the commands manually in the terminal. This solution is ONLY ABOUT the authentication part:

I had to install sshpass.

```
sshpass -p thepassword sftp theuser@ftp.thesite.com
```

Then you will be logged on sftp to run commands manually, without having to type the password.