# SFTP command in Bash script with Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, sftp

I need to transfer a text file to a remote PC (freeSSH) using SFTP and SSH from a Mac host. These two are connected in a local network.

So is there a way to run an SFTP command (with the username and password provided) from inside the Bash script?

I already tried some scripting with `expect`, but I didn't get any results.

I found a similar post, *[How to run the sftp command with a password from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386482/how-to-run-sftp-command-with-a-password-from-bash-script)*, but it is for Linux. I have a Mac.

Comment: I had the same requirements a while back and ended up using Perl's `Net::SFTP` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download and install sshpass on Mac as well. Get the latest version source from [this download link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/files/sshpass/)

Rest of the steps on using sshpass are there in the linked answer of mine.

Answer (score 3):

`lftp` is great for scripting ftp (and sftp, ftps). And you can install it with [brew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install lftp
```

Answer (score 1):

And for installing the latest version of sshpass using homebrew:

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EasyG0ing1/sshpassBrew/main/Formula/sshpass.rb
```

You might have to do this to install it:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EasyG0ing1/sshpassBrew/main/Formula/sshpass.rb

brew install sshpass.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @anubhava's answer is correct, it points to the sources only and compiling it without help is hard.

To install `sshpass` on MacOS using `brew` easily please use this unofficial package:

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadwanev/bigboybrew/master/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/arunoda/7790979