# Shell Script to load multiple FTP files

Tags: shell, syntax-error, ftp-client

I am trying to upload multiple files from one folder to a ftp site and wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in '/dir/*'
do 
if [-f /dir/$i]; then
HOST='x.x.x.x'
USER='username'
PASSWD='password'
DIR=archives
File=$i

ftp -n $HOST << END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
ascii
put $FILE   
quit    
END_SCRIPT
fi
```

It is giving me following error when I try to execute:

```
username@host:~/Documents/Python$ ./script.sh 
./script.sh: line 22: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I can't seem to get this to work. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mayank

Comment: The 'unexpected end of file' is because you have a `for` loop without a matching `done` at the end.

Comment: To make it easier for your helpers, please indent the control structure bodies of `for`, `if` etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining because your `for` loop does not have a `done` marker to indicate the end of the loop. You also need more spaces in your `if`:

```
if [ -f "$i" ]; then
```

Recall that `[` is actually a command, and it won't be recognized if it doesn't appear as such.

And... if you single quote your glob (at the `for`) like that, it won't be expanded. No quotes there, but double quotes when using `$i`. You probably also don't want to include the `/dir/` part when you use `$i` as it's included in your glob.

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested and getting following error: **user@host:~/Documents/Python$ ./script.sh 
Bad sequence of commands.
Bad sequence of commands.
(local-file) (remote-file) 
Bad sequence of commands.
Bad sequence of commands.
(local-file) (remote-file)**

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, [`ncftp`](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) can take wildcard arguments:

```
ncftpput -u username -p password x.x.x.x archives /dir/*
```

If you don't already have it installed, it's likely available in the standard repo for your OS.

Comment: `lftp` can also do this (it has an `mput` command to do a single, multi-file put).

Comment: Also, I don't think your command here uses ASCII mode, making it different from the original script.

Comment: Surely it's fair to expect the OP to do a *little* of the work... :)

Answer (score 0):

First, the literal, fixing-your-script answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
# no reason to set variables that don't change inside the loop
host='x.x.x.x'
user='username'
password='password'
dir=archives
for i in /dir/*; do # no quotes if you want the wildcard to be expanded!
  if [ -f "$i" ]; then # need double quotes and whitespace here!
    file=$i
    ftp -n "$host" <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $user
quote PASS $password
ascii
put $file $dir/$file
quit    
END_SCRIPT
  fi
done
```

Next, the easy way:

```
lftp -e 'mput -a *.i' -u "$user,$password" "ftp://$host/"
```

(yes, lftp expands the wildcard internally, rather than expecting this to be done by the outer shell).

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the suggestions. It really helps. I have changed my script to what Charles suggested and when I execute it I get following errors: username@host:~/Documents/Python$ ./script.sh 
Bad sequence of commands.
Bad sequence of commands.
(local-file) (remote-file) 
Bad sequence of commands.
Bad sequence of commands.
(local-file) (remote-file)

Comment: @user1354065 FTP implementations vary, so no one script can be guaranteed to work across all of them. Might I suggest you try the lftp version?

Comment: @user1354065 ...that said, on review -- variable capitalization was inconsistent; the name was being assigned to `$File`, but `$FILE` was being dereferenced. For variables not exported into the environment, using all-uppercase is actually contrary to convention, so I've updated this to use all-lowercase.

Comment: Thanks Charles! I tried to execute the script the way as you updated above and it gives following message `user@host:~/Documents/Python$ ./updated.sh 
Bad sequence of commands.
Bad sequence of commands.
Bad sequence of commands.
Bad sequence of commands.`

Comment: I also changed the script to `#!/bin/bash
host='x.x.x.x'
user='uname'
passwd='passwd'
dir='archives/sfg'
lftp -e 'mput -a /localdir/*.*' -u "$user,$passwd" "sftp://$host/"` and its getting hung up at following message `user@host:~/Documents/Python$ ./script.sh 
cd ok, cwd=/                                         
`...abc.log' at 20 [Sending data]` and then I have to hit CTRL+C to stop it as it is taking forever.

Comment: @maksaraswat err, sftp? that's a completely different protocol than ftp; which one do you actually want to use?

Comment: I can only login to the the site by using sftp ("sftp uname@host") and not ftp ("ftp uname@host"). So, it is sftp (my bad for not being clear).

Comment: @maksaraswat ...then this entire question is misguided, since it starts out with FTP, not SFTP, as a premise.

Answer (score 0):

First of all my apologies in not making myself clear in the question. My actual task was to copy a file from local folder to a SFTP site and then move the file to an archive folder. Since the SFTP is hosted by a vendor I cannot use the key sharing (vendor limitation. Also, SCP will require password entering if used in a shell script so I have to use SSHPASS. SSHPASS is in the Ubuntu repo however for CentOS it needs to be installed [from here](http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/epel-x86_64/sshpass-1.05-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html)

Current thread and [How to run the sftp command with a password from Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386482/how-to-run-sftp-command-with-a-password-from-bash-script) did gave me better understanding on how to write the script and I will share my solution here:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin

for i in /dir/*; do 
 if [ -f "$i" ]; then 
file=$i
    export SSHPASS=password
    sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - user@ftp.com << !
    cd foldername/foldername
    put $file
 bye
 !
mv $file /somedir/test
fi
done
```

Thanks everyone for all the responses!
--Mayank