# How to send password using sftp batch file

Tags: batch-file, passwords, sftp

I'm trying to download a file from sftp site using batch script. I'm getting the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

When running  the command:

```
sftp -b /home/batchfile.sftp <user>@<server ip>:<folder>
```

the `batchfile.sftp` includes these data:

```
password
lcd [local folder]
cd [sftp server folder]
get *
bye
```

Note: It's working when running at the prompt as

```
sftp <user>@<server ip>:<folder>
```

But I need the ability to enter the password automatically.

Comment: Is it working, by removing the password from the batchfile ? Does the remaining functionality work well, by entering the password manually?

Comment: Storing the password in plain text in a file is obviously not secure - if you don't want to type in a password every time I strongly suggest using RSA key authentication.

Comment: @lindhe Storing the password in a plain text file is obviously going to be just as secure as using RSA key authentication without a password on the key. Which is really the only option if you're going to automate things. Just make sure the plain text file is only readable by the owner of the file (just like what is required for ssh keys)

Comment: just a thought, but one approach I use that seems as secure as local private ssh keys is to put the file in the ~/.ssh directory with same perms as .ssh/{your_private_keyfile_name}.  I do not recommend the approaches below that put the password in .bashrc, especially putting it in an export variable.  .bashrc gets read by soooo many processes, and the password is in "plain text" in your environment variables.  When in doubt, do it .ssh style :)

Answer (score 62):

You'll want to install the sshpass program. Then:

`sshpass -p YOUR_PASSWORD sftp -oBatchMode=no -b YOUR_COMMAND_FILE_PATH USER@HOST`

Obviously, it's better to setup public key authentication. Only use this if that's impossible to do, for whatever reason.

Comment: Thank you! This is the only comment that actually answers the question. There are times it's simply not possible to get a keyfile.

Comment: To do this safer put `export SSHPASS='your_password'` to `~/.bashrc`  and run with `-e` flag. I have used this cmd in some project like this: `echo 'ls -t upload/*.xml' | sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - user@example.com | grep -v "sftp>" | head -n1`

Comment: Taking @Lev Lukomsky's a step further you'd want to remove group and world read permissions from ~/.bashrc.

Comment: I recommend "not" putting in .bashrc because that is a promiscuous file read all the time.  And especially don't put your password in an exported variable or anywhere that shows up in .bash_history... both are basically going to put it in plain text and keep it resident in memory... no good.  put it in your .ssh/ directory, in a file with same permissions as your ssh private key, and never use it in a way that keeps it resident in memory, displayable by 'ps', or in your environment.  Stay ssh'y !

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386482/how-to-run-the-sftp-command-with-a-password-from-bash-script using sshpass -e and the SSHPASS env var is a safer way to go rather than passing the password on the command line which is visible to all users on the host.

Comment: Thanks for this!  It never ceases to amuse me how one program uses an option but in order to use that option you have to tell the helper program not to use that option...  use SFTP with a batch file but tell SSH not to use a batch file.  Brilliant  :-)

Answer (score 27):

If you are generating a heap of commands to be run, then call that script from a terminal, you can try the following.

```
sftp login@host < /path/to/command/list
```

You will then be asked to enter your password (as per normal) however all the commands in the script run after that.

This is clearly not a completely automated option that can be used in a `cron` job, but it can be used from a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

```
PSFTP -b path/file_name.sftp user@IP_server -hostkey 1e:52:b1... -pw password
```

the file content is:

```
lcd "path_file for send"

cd path_destination

mput file_name_to_send

quit
```

to have the hostkey run:

```
psftp  user@IP_SERVER
```

Comment: for Windows user, `psftp` is a command line tool installed together with [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/) while `sshpass` is not available. see https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter6.html

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to run sftp with -v option. It becomes much easier to fathom what is happening.

The manual clearly states:

> The final usage format allows for automated sessions using the -b
>   option.
>        In such cases, it is necessary to configure non-interactive authentication
>         to obviate the need to enter a password at connection time (see
>        sshd(8) and ssh-keygen(1) for details).

In other words you have to establish a publickey authentication. Then you'll be able to run a batch script.

P.S.
It is wrong to put your password in your batch file.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it is the opposite of what the question asks. The "P.S." element seems like a topic that is worthwhile to explore. Things are rarely "right" or "wrong" but compromises and tradeoffs of different factors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the command pscp and forcing it to pass through sftp protocol. pscp is automatically installed when you install PuttY, a software to connect to a linux server through ssh.

When you have your pscp command here is the command line:

```
pscp -sftp -pw <yourPassword> "<pathToYourFile(s)>" <username>@<serverIP>:<PathInTheServerFromTheHomeDirectory>
```

These parameters (-sftp and -pw) are only available with pscp and not scp. You can also add -r if you want to upload everything in a folder in a recursive way.

Answer (score 0):

You mention batch files, am I correct then assuming that you're talking about a Windows system? If so you cannot use sshpass, and you will have to switch to a different option.

Two of such options, that follow diametrically opposite philosophies are:

- psftp: command-line tool that you can call from within your batch scripts; psftp is part of the PuTTY package and you can find it here http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

  Syncplify.me FTP Script: a scriptable FTP/S and SFTP client for Windows that allows you to store your password in encrypted "profile files"; check it out here http://www.syncplify.me/products/ftp-script/

Either way, switching from password to PKI authentication is strongly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This command will help you

```
sshpass -p MYPASSWORD sftp MYUSERNAME@HOST
```

Answer (score 0):

One can do that by using standard expect tool:

```
SFTP_SERVER='myserver.com'
SFTP_USER='mysftp_user'
SFTP_PWD='12345'

SFTP_BATCH=sftp.bat  #existing batch file with sftp commands to execute

SFTP_IGNORE_PUBKEY='-o "PubkeyAuthentication=no"'   # optional param

expect <<EOF
        set timeout 120
        spawn sftp -q -o "BatchMode=no" $SFTP_IGNORE_PUBKEY -b "$SFTP_SCRIPT" "$SFTP_USER@$SFTP_SERVER"
        expect  {
            -nocase "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" { send "yes\r" ; exp_continue}
            -nocase "*password:" { send "$SFTP_PWD\r"; exp_continue }
            -nocase -re "failed|invalid password|timeout" abort
        }
        catch wait result
        exit [lindex \$result 3]  #catch and forward sftp result code
EOF
    rc=$?
echo $rc
```

Here:

- `-o "BatchMode=no"` to allow interaction
- `-q` - quite execution, avoids having long 'server greetings' msg in log
- expect code to answer yes and password when needed, as well as intercept exit code of sftp process.