# Download excel file from sFtp server using batch file

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, sftp

I am looking for a code like we have in ftp for sftp which can be used to connect the server and from the given path downloads the file requested.

Can this be done using a batch file or excel macro anyway direction would be appreciated.

I cannot use any client to do this job it has to be a batch file or macro that does the work.

EDIT:

Batch Code

```
open your.ftpserver.com
user yourUsername yourPassword
lcd C:\Downloads
cd yourRemoteFolder
binary
get "East Vat Account.xlsx"
bye
```

Macro to run batch file

```
Public Sub Ftp_Download_File()

    Dim FTPcommand As String
    Dim wsh As Object

    FTPcommand = "ftp -n -s:" & Chr(34) & "C:\FTP_commands.txt" & Chr(34)
    Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wsh.Run FTPcommand, 5, True

    Workbooks.Open "C:\Downloads\East Vat Account.xlsx"

End Sub
```

Comment: If i understand, you have some code that handles FTP bu you want it to use SFTP instead. Can you please post the FTP code and maybe we can help you to modify it to use SFTP

Comment: Sure thing. I will edit the above post and put a FTP code that i have

Comment: can't you juste use the `sftp`command?

Comment: i tried using sftp instead ftp but did not work

Comment: Can you elaborate on _did not work_ what error did you get?

Comment: It says connected, then connection closed by  host and then on user name pass it says not connected. when i try any client the same things work flawlessly

Comment: it seems that sftp does not have the same parameters as FTP https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sftp&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+10.3-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html

Comment: So how do i change these parameters ?? can you help?

Comment: I think you're out of luck... http://stackoverflow.com/a/17768124/3072566 seems to be impossible unless you setup key authentication or change client

Comment: Show us your SFTP code. Why are you showing the FTP code, if you want to use SFTP? Also make sure you understand if you want SFTP (over SSH) or FTPS (FTP over TLS/SSL).

Comment: Hello i have completed the code and used WINSCP as a medium to connect and download and it worked for me.