# SFTP Connection with out password prompt

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to move txt/ log file from server1 to server2.

I am trying to connect to a server from server1 to server2 using SFTP but some how it is asking for password in the prompt.Can anyone let me know how to give password as input through script and execute this functionality using a Script.
Please let me know asap......

MY CODE:

test.sh is script and 1.txt file has password details.....

code: test.sh
sftp mwctrl@sacsun11 < 1.txt <> out.log 2>&1
cd /usr/ftadapters/logs/adapters/rivaadp
lcd /export/home/eisape
put *.txt
exit
EOF

1.txt:
password m33tzn3

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run sftp command with a password from bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386482/how-to-run-sftp-command-with-a-password-from-bash-script)

Answer (score 2):

Actually you need add ssh keys to remote machine. Check article below:

[Using sftp without password (http://says-story.blogspot.nl/2008/01/using-ssh-scp-sftp-without-password.html)](http://says-story.blogspot.nl/2008/01/using-ssh-scp-sftp-without-password.html)

Comment: I am new to Unix.Is it really mandatory to asdd ssh keys , cant we write a script to automatically give the password as input...I am able to do the task using FTP using Quote command...

Answer (score 0):

Setting up ssh keys is relatively simple. Takes **<1 min** following the instructions in the link posted above by fxzuz.

But generally passing passwords as parameters / storing in config files is considered a security risk.

However, if you still want to go ahead, here is a link -- http://nixcraft.com/shell-scripting/4489-ssh-passing-unix-login-passwords-through-shell-scripts.html

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn sftp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no mwctrl@sacsun11 \
"cd /usr/ftadapters/logs/adapters/rivaadp \
lcd /export/home/eisape \
put *.txt \"
expect "*?assword:*"
send  "m33tzn3"
send  "\r"
set timeout -1
send  "\r"
expect EOF
```