# pass password to sftp in a bash script

Tags: bash, passwords, sftp

I would like to automate a bash script, that connects to server using sftp and does a file transfer. I have the password for this, and initially I tried for this

```
sftp $acc@$host << EOF
<passwd_here>
cd $dir
get $file
quit
EOF
```

but it still prompted for password, and I had to enter it manually at the prompt.

After searching SO, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386482/how-to-run-the-sftp-command-with-a-password-from-bash-script) which had a solution with `expect`, which I tried and I got the following error:

Script:

```
sftp -b cmdfile.txt $acc@$host
expect "Password:"
send "<passwd>\n";
interact
```

Error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

`cmdfile.txt`

```
cd $dir
get $file
quit
```

Please let me know, How to connect using the password in a bash script?

Comment: Better `expect scripts` can be written but I would suggest getting sshpass on your client host. sshpass is more secured and less error prone than sftp.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

With scp/sftp you should use key-based authentication. Public key from the user you want to authenticate copy into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on the server, into home directory of user on which you want log on. Storing password in clear text on client side is not a good practice, you know :) That way you "workaround" problem of reading password from the prompt too.

Comment: The remote host has provided the password. I can't set the public keys on the host. Please let me know the way to pass it in the script.

Comment: What do you mean by "remote host provided the password" ? If it'd have provide password for logging-in user, logging would not make sense at all. If you're able to use scp/sftp, then you're probably able to copy public key on remote server, to remote user's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ( or "authorized_keys2" .. generate your keys with ssh-keygen..

Answer (score 5):

Please try the below steps

```
lftp -u $user,$pass sftp://$host << --EOF--
cd $directory
put $srcfile
quit
--EOF--
```

Comment: I'd never heard of `lftp` before; this is a very useful solution for those of us who don't have the option of setting up SSH keys. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Yes key-based auth is the way to go.
Check [here](http://technonstop.com/automatic-login-ssh-sftp-ubuntu) for some direction.