# Sftp unix batchfile

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Intitally i wrote below script to do sftp using rsa keys,i mean without password.

Now i want user/password authentication first then RSA public key authentication.What amendments required in below to provide user name and password and any keys to be installed in unix machine?

export SFTP_BATCH_FILE='/var/tmp/SFTP_BATCH_FILE'

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create sftp script
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
rm -f $SFTP_BATCH_FILE
echo "lcd $SOURCE_FILE_DIRECTORY " > $SFTP_BATCH_FILE
echo "cd $DESTINATION_FILE_DIRECTORY " >> $SFTP_BATCH_FILE
if [ -z $FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTD ] then
echo "put $FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTD " >> $SFTP_BATCH_FILE
fi
if [ -z $FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTDF ] then
echo "put $FILE_TO_UPLOAD_TESTDF " >> $SFTP_BATCH_FILE
fi
echo "bye" >> $SFTP_BATCH_FILE

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Do sftp
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo " Before SFTP " >> $LOG_FILE
if [[ -z $ FILE_TO_UPLOAD && -z $ FILE_TO_UPLOAD1 ]] then
 echo “No files to transfer” >> $LOG_FILE
       mv $LOG_FILE $LOG_DIRECTORY
 exit 1
else 
echo “Attempting to connect to  Remote Server $REMOTE_SERVER_PROD” >> $LOG_FILE
/usr/bin/sftp –v -oPort=$SFTP_PORT -b $SFTP_BATCH_FILE $SOURCE_FUNCTIONAL_ID@$REMOTE_SERVER_PROD >> $LOG_FILE 2 >> $LOG_FILE
fi
```

Regards,
Chai

Comment: Will this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386482/how-to-run-the-sftp-command-with-a-password-from-bash-script/5386587 ?

Comment: I will check your link,Do i require any key setup ?

Comment: How to do with batch mode,i have lot other commands to execute after successful user and pasword authentication

Comment: If you decide to use sshpass (as shown in my linked answer) you can run as many commands after authenticating with your username/password.

Comment: Thanks,How to amend above of my codewithout using batch mode?

Comment: you can use **expet** scripts, but better use key auth

Comment: Before this line `echo "bye" >> $SFTP_BATCH_FILE` you can add all those extra sftp commands ou want to add.

Comment: Not sure ,how to do this.how to amend this line /usr/bin/sftp –v -oPort=$SFTP_PORT -b $SFTP_BATCH_FILE $SOURCE_FUNCTIONAL_ID@$REMOTE_SERVER_PROD >> $LOG_FILE 2 >> $LOG_FILE .By passing password

Comment: dont' have sshpass,keychain and expect modules.how to do in this case?