# How to transfer a file using sftp in UNIX

Tags: sftp

I want to transfer a .png file from a directory on my computer to a directory on a remote server.

I have to use SFTP to secure the file and transfer mode.  And I already have a UNIX script (.ksh) file to copy the files in the normal mode. How do I implement the transfer in SFTP mode?

Comment: Post the script in you `.ksh` file here!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `sftp` instead of whatever command you are using in your *.ksh* script. See [sftp man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp) for reference.

You may also want to look at `scp` secure copy - [scp man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp).

#### EDIT

`sftp` is mostly for interactive operations, you need to specify host you want to connect to:

```
sftp example.com
```

you will be prompted for username and passsword, and the interactive session will begin..

Although it can be used in scripts, the `scp` is much more easy to use:

```
scp /path/to/localfile user@host:/path/to/dest
```

you will be prompted for password..

#### Edit 2

Both `scp` and `sftp` use `ssh` as underlying protocol, see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/134901/whats-the-difference-between-scp-and-sftp) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/74164/difference-between-scp-and-sftp)

The best way to setup them to run from scripts is to setup passwordless authentication using *keys*. See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) and [this](http://www.csua.berkeley.edu/~ranga/notes/ssh_nopass.html). I use this extensively on my servers.. After you setup keys, you can run

```
scp -i private-key-file /path/to/local/file user@host:/path/to/remote

sftp -oIdentityFile=private-key-file -b batch-file user@host
```

If you want to authenticate with password, you may try the `expect` package. The simplest script may look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sftp -b batch-file user@host
expect "*?assword:*"
send "pasword\n"
interact
```

See [this](http://fixunix.com/ssh/530359-how-supply-sftp-password.html#post1719551), [this](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/198125-sftp-scp-using-password.html) and [this](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/21466-automating-sftp-expect.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

### Send commands through sftp on one line:

**Make a file and save it as my_batch_file:**

```
cd /root
get blah.txt
bye
```

**Run this to execute your batch file:**

```
eric@dev /home/el $ sftp root@10.30.25.15 < my_batch_file
Connecting to 10.30.25.15...
Password:
sftp> cd /root
sftp> get blah.txt
Fetching /root/blah.txt to blah.txt
sftp> bye
```

**The file is transferred**

That moved the `blah.txt` from remote computer to local computer.

**If you don't want to specify a password, do this:**

[How to run the sftp command with a password from Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386482/how-to-run-the-sftp-command-with-a-password-from-bash-script)

**Or if you want to do it the hacky insecure way, use bash and expect:**

```
#!/bin/bash
expect -c "
spawn sftp username@your_host
expect \"Password\"
send \"your_password_here\r\"
interact "
```

You may need to install expect, change the wording of 'Password' to lowercase 'p' to match what your prompt receives.  The problems here is that it exposes your password in plain text in the file as well as in the command history.  Which nearly defeats the purpose of having a password in the first place.