# Permission denied to use sftp -b batch file

Tags: sftp

I can log in to my remote using ssh/sftp (without the -b option)

```
sftp root@192.168.7.2
```

But when I try

```
sftp -b commands.tmp root@192.168.7.2
```

I get

```
Permission denied (publickey,password).
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Commands.tmp looks like this

```
ls
exit
```

Anything I am missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are authentication with a password or an encrypted private key, you cannot use the `-b` with plain `sftp`. The [`sftp` man](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp) says:

> Since it lacks user interaction it should be used in conjunction with non-interactive authentication

You can for example use a passphrase-less private key together with the `-b`.

---

If you want to use password authentication, you need to use workarounds like `sshpass`. See:
[How to run the sftp command with a password from Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5386482/850848)

Answer (score 4):

I used shhpass to write the password no interactive and I needed to add `-oBatchMode=no`

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD sftp -v -oBatchMode=no -b FILE USER@SERVER
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
sshpass -p 'PASSWORDSTRING' sftp -v -oBatchMode=no -b deploy/production username@ipaddress
```

production file

```
put -rp /from-directory /to-directory
```

Comment: thank you that worked for me; however for some reason it is important that the "-oBatchMode=no" is before the "-b" option.