# Provide password to ssh command inside bash script, Without the usage of public keys and Expect

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I want to use `SSH` inside a script, but this script is not going to be executed on my machine.

In my implementation there are two limitations.

- I can not work outside shell's standards,therefore i can not use `expect` because i do not know if it will be available on this machine.
- I can not expect that this machine will have `public keys` for the `SSH`.

What are the possible options-solutions ?

How can i provide ssh with the requested password with an automated and secure way without adding extra dependencies?

Will it be possible to provide the password inside the script?

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: Are other languages like perl or python available?

Comment: normally yes, but in python i know that it is possible :) Thank you anyway

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all: **Don't put secrets in clear text** *unless* you know why it is a safe thing to do (i.e. you have assessed what damage can be done by an attacker knowing the secret).

If you are ok with putting secrets in your script, you could ship an ssh key with it and execute in an `ssh-agent` shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ssh-agent /usr/bin/env bash
KEYFILE=`mktemp`
cat << EOF > ${KEYFILE}
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
[.......]
EOF
ssh-add ${KEYFILE}

# do your ssh things here...

# Remove the key file.
rm -f ${KEYFILE}
```

A benefit of using ssh keys is that you can easily use [forced commands](http://binblog.info/2008/10/20/openssh-going-flexible-with-forced-commands/) to limit what the keyholder can do on the server.

A more secure approach would be to let the script run `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/my-script-key` to create a private key specific for this purpose, but then you would also need a routine for adding the public key to the server.

Comment: I start concluding that generating a private key for the needs of the script and after removing it will be the only solution.Thank you very much

Comment: It was the closest answer to my question :) Thank you

Answer (score 29):

Install sshpass, then launch the command:

```
sshpass -p "yourpassword" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no yourusername@hostname
```

Comment: Thank you very much,but i cant expect that the computer that i will run the script will have sshpass installed,thats the reason i cant use expect.

Answer (score 17):

For security reasons you must avoid providing password on a command line otherwise anyone running ps command can see your password. Better to use [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) utility like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export SSHPASS="your-password"
sshpass -e ssh -oBatchMode=no sshUser@remoteHost
```

You might be interested in **[How to run the sftp command with a password from Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386482/how-to-run-the-sftp-command-with-a-password-from-bash-script)**

Comment: Thank you very much,but i cant expect that the computer that i will run the script will have sshpass installed,thats the reason i cant use expect.

Comment: Yes it may not be installed already but you can download it from the provided link and compile it yourself. It doesn't require any admin privileges.

Comment: Will i have to downloaded it in every computer that i want to run the script on ?If its something that i can just implement to my code , its okay , but i just want to create a standalone script that it will be able to run everywhere without the need of permissions,extra packages.Thats the reason i wanted to stay to the standard.

Answer (score 2):

*I completely agree with everybody who says this is almost certainly a **very bad idea**.  However, if you've evaluated your needs and want to know how it is done, **it is certainly possible without using keys and without installing any other programs**, just using Bourne Shell mechanisms.*

***USE AT YOUR OWN RISK AFTER EVALUATING THE SECURITY HAZARDS***

## Answer

Make a program `/path/to/saypass` which outputs the password, such as this minimal script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'secret'
```

Make it executable with

```
chmod +x /path/to/saypass
```

Then this is the main command:

```
SSH_ASKPASS="/path/to/saypass" DISPLAY=anything setsid ssh username@hostname [farcommand]
```

In brief, this runs `ssh` in a special way which uses your `saypass` program to get the password. (`/path/to` must be replaced with the path to your script; `anything` is can be literally this string; replace `username@hostname` by your details.)

In detail:

- sets the two environment variables `SSH_ASKPASS` and `DISPLAY`

  - and then runs `setsid`

    - which then runs `ssh` without a controlling terminal

      - which connects to the far `hostname`
      - ... runs `saypass` locally to get the password
      - ... tells it to the far server
      - ... and assuming it's correct

        - which then runs `farcommand` (if given), or an interactive shell.

I normally test with `date` or `hostname` for the optional `farcommand`.

There are lots of places for this to go wrong.

## Explanation

The trick to this is that standard Linux command line `ssh` has a couple of environment variables you can use to choose a program which gets executed to supply the password.  This is designed to be used with an X11 user interface, but can be used for our purpose.

The `ssh(1)` manual page says:

> `SSH_ASKPASS` If `ssh` needs a passphrase, it will read the passphrase from the current terminal if it was run from a terminal.  **If `ssh` does not have a terminal associated with it but `DISPLAY` and `SSH_ASKPASS` are set, it will execute the program specified by `SSH_ASKPASS`** and open an X11 window to read the passphrase.

So: you need a program (shell script or any other kind) which will output the password.  Then you need to convince `ssh` to use it:

- With `SSH_ASKPASS` set to `/path/to/saypass`
- With `DISPLAY` set to something silly
- With no controlling terminal (this is what `setsid` does)

Which you put together in the following `sh` command:

```
SSH_ASKPASS="/path/to/saypass" DISPLAY=anything setsid ssh username@hostname [command]
```

`ssh` will execute one of these two commands:

```
/path/to/saypass "Password:"
/path/to/saypass "username@hostname's password:"
```

## Fingerprint check

If the fingerprint is needed, where you'd normally see the message

```
The authenticity of host '*hostname* (*ipaddress*)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Then `ssh` will run your command like this:

```
/path/to/saypass "Please type 'yes' or 'no':"
```

## All-in-one script

The following is a single script for creating, using, and removing a `saypass` within the main script.  Everyone will tell you **do not put plaintext passwords in files** and also **never hardcode a password**.  They tell you this for good reason: it will cause you a lot of trouble.  Use at your own risk.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "#!/bin/sh\necho 'secret';rm -f /tmp/saypass.$$" > /tmp/saypass.$$
chmod 775 /tmp/saypass.$$
SSH_ASKPASS="/tmp/saypass.$$" DISPLAY=anything setsid ssh "$@"
```

## SCP

This also works for `scp`, the copy program on top of `ssh`:

```
SSH_ASKPASS=/path/to/saypas DISPLAY=anything setsid scp username@hostname:/path/to/farfile .
```

## Caveat

Really don't use this except in dire, dire, circumstances, such as where you have hundreds of computers and you can't install anything like ssh keys, `sshpass` even `expect`.

If you have to use this technique, put your passwords in a file and make `saypass` get it from there.  Make `saypass` as secure as you're able; you can pass information into it through the environment.

I don't know what the man page means about "open an X11 window", no such thing happens in my testing.

Tested on

- OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS,
- OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016 on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
- OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017 on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no possibility beside from using keys or expect if you are using the command line version `ssh`. But there are library bindings for the most programming languages like C, python, php, ... . You could write a program in such a language. This way it would be possible to pass the password automatically. But **note** this is of course a security problem as the password will be stored in plain text in that program

Comment: thank you :) You were helpful at least by showing me what is possible.I thought about developing in python but the lines of code for an ssh command in python is like 100 times more than in shell version ssh :)

Comment: The problem is just, that the `ssh` command expects the  password coming from a terminal. that's why expect as it simulates a terminal. Maybe one can do the same in an easy way. I don't know how. However you should find that 100 lines using google ;)