# how to pass password to sftp connection in shell script

Tags: bash, unix

I have an sftp connection to a server in Unix. 
Without password, I use the syntax to connect and execute command

sftp -b  $user@$server_name

Can anyone suggest me how can I write a shell script to connect a remote server non interactively using a password

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386482/how-to-run-the-sftp-command-with-a-password-from-bash-script?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Try with this below option,

```
lftp -u $user,$pass sftp://$host << --EOF--
cd $directory
put $srcfile
quit
```

--EOF--

Answer (score 1):

You could use ~/.ssh/config file.

```
#
# ~/.ssh/config
#

Host servername
Hostname 127.127.127.127
Port 22
User root

#EOF: config
```

Then simply connect with "ssh servername" and if you don't want to use password you can use SSH key. Here is good tutorial on how to do that > http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-multiple-ssh-key-based-authentication.html

If you just want to pass user/server from terminal, you can do this.

```
#!/bin/bash
sftp -b "$1"@"$2"
```

then use it like this './sftp.sh user server'

use SCP like this;

```
scp -P 22 user@server:/dir/file.tgz ~/Desktop/
```

use SFTP like this;

```
sftp user@server:/dir/file.tgz ~/Desktop/file.tgz
```

You can also try this;

```
sftp user@host <<EOF
get /dir/file.tgz
rm /dir/file.tgz
EOF
```

Comment: I don't have root access or don't have the external access. I need to utilize the existing details and use

Comment: I am trying to download the files from the external server

Comment: after successful transfer, I am supposed to delete the files as well

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to create a key pair on the client, and add the key to the target user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

To create a key pair, run `ssh-keygen` and when it asks for a password, just hit return to indicate "no password". Then either run `ssh-copy-id $user@$server_name` or manually create a `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server and copy the contents of the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` from the client into it (`ssh-copy-id` isn't available on all machines, so on some you'll have to do it manually).

Now you should be able to run `ssh` or `scp` without a password, as it should use your key instead. If it doesn't work, make sure that the permissions on your `~/.ssh/` directory and contents are correct on both machines; the directory should be `0700` (`drwx------`) and the files should be `600` (`-rw-------`). Also check that key authentication is enabled on both the client and the server.

Comment: I have neither root access nor the control on external server. I can connect to the remote server using sftp connecting by entering the password

Comment: @Trinadh If that's the case, then the answer about using `expect` is probably the best you can do. But if possible, you should see if the administrator can set up key based authentication for you, as it's simpler and more secure.

Comment: @Trinadh Can you log into that remote machine. Then you don't need root or _control_ privileges. `ssh-keygen` operates on the user level. You run the command on the server (to create a private key) and on your _client_ (to create a public key). You then copy your private key into the `authorized_keys` file. I do it all of the time.