# Use of sftp with shell_exec php

Tags: php, passwords, sftp, shell-exec

I'm trying to get a file from a remote host but it asks me the password and the script is supposed to run without me to type the password. How can I send the password? I have to use shell_exec.

```
<?php
    $command="sftp  user@ip adress";
    shell_exec($command);
?>
```

Comment: Check the answers for this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/5386482/1301076 - the same applies here

Comment: I can't install sshpass in this machine

Comment: sshpass is just one of the options. Consider them all, at least one will be suitable. `expect` for example. (note that you will need to create a script and call that instead of sftp directly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation: use something like [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

// copies filename.remote to filename.local from the SFTP server
$sftp->get('filename.remote', 'filename.local');
?>
```