# Robot Framework OperatingSystem and or Process

Tags: robotframework

I have the below script and it executes correctly however I cant get passed the section when system prompts password. I would like to have RF enter the password for me. How can I get this accomplished?

```
    *** Settings ***
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  Process


*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
Login to Server
      Run  sftp -o "Port 44444" username@mysite.com
```

Side note: Im trying to drop a file into our sftp server.. I know Robot has SSHLibrary, however, due to security we are blocking SSH calls to this server.

Once I get passed the login process I was thinking the rest should be easy.

Comment: Linux? If so, [look at the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386482/how-to-run-the-sftp-command-with-a-password-from-bash-script), private key, sshpass or expect will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to go through the command line, then please take [@Todor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3446126/todor)'s comment to heart and use private keys and that way prevent having to fill in the password at all.

An alternative approach is to create a custom Robot Framework Python Library based on an already existing Python SFTP Client Module, like for example [cis-yogesh - Python_sftp_client](https://github.com/cis-yogesh/Python_sftp_client) and convert it to a Robot Library.