# How to build script bash with SFTP connection to pull files

Tags: bash, unix, sftp

I'm implementing agent script bash to pull files from the remote server with SFTP service.
The script must:

1. connect SFTP
2. file listing
3. cycling on files found
4. get every file and copy agent side
5. after that files copied must be deleted

The script is followed:

```
 #!/bin/bash

SFTP_CONNECTION="sftp -oIdentityFile=/home/account_xxx/.ssh/service_ssh user@host"

DEST_DATA=/tmp/test/data/

# GET list file by ls command ###############

$SFTP_CONNECTION
$LIST_FILES_DATA_OSM1 = $("ls fromvan/test/data/test_1")
echo $LIST_FILES_DATA_OSM1


for file in "${LIST_FILES_DATA_OSM1[@]}"
       do
                $SFTP_CONNECTION get $file $DEST_DATA
                $SFTP_CONNECTION rm $file
       done
```

I tried the script but it seems that the connection and command execution (ls) are distinct on thread separated. 
How can I provide command sequential as described above ?

Screenshoot:

[image]

Invalid find command

[image]

SSH it seem not available

[image]

RSYNC result to take the files is the followed:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: try use `rsync` + `rm -rf fromvan/test/data/test_1/*`

Comment: is not available server side RSYNC  deamon

Comment: what problem for install it? But with rsync u can do it more faster with only 2 line code...

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-copy-files-with-rsync-over-ssh

Comment: I can only access by SFTP on the Server. I can't install nothing

Comment: As there is such a limitation of the commands available maybe you have less restrictions if you connect via SSH?

Comment: It seem that SSH is not available. Look last screenshoot

Comment: sftp work over SSH, also rsync can be run from any point to sync - need only SSH

Comment: @beliy, not always true. It's possible to lock down SSH to only allow the sftp subsystem, and not programs -- such as rsync -- that require shell access.

Comment: If you want to copy all files in a local directory to a remote one, or the inverse, you'll have a better time of it using `lftp` as your sftp client.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17826579/14122 looks pretty much on-point.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would recommend the following syntax changes:

```
#!/bin/bash

sftp_connection() { 
    sftp -oIdentityFile=/home/account_xxx/.ssh/service_ssh user@host "$@"; 
}

Dest_Data=/tmp/test/data/

# GET list file by ls command ###############

sftp_connection
List_Files_D_OSM1=$("ls fromvan/test/data/test_1")
echo "$LIST_FILES_DATA_OSM1"


for file in "${LIST_FILES_DATA_OSM1[@]}"
    do
        sftp_connection get "$file" $Dest_Data
        sftp_connection rm "$file"
    done
```

- Quoting `$file` and `$List_Files_D_OSM1` to prevent globbing and word splitting.
- Assignments can't start with a `$`, otherwise bash will try to execute `List_Files_D_OSM1` and will complain with a `command not found`
- No white spaces in assignments like `List_Files_D_OSM1 = $("ls fromvan/test/data/test_1")`

**You can use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to catch this kind of errors.**

---

Having said that, [it is in general not a good idea to use `ls` in such way.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

What you can use instead is something like [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find). For example:

`find . -type d -exec echo '{}' \;`

Comment: @Stefano what do you mean? How does your code look exactly? You could edit it to your question

Comment: it mean that sftp protocol can't perform the command because it not available, My code is the same as described. If I perform the script it try the connetion ad show to screen    sftp>  . it's waiting the command. I update the post with screenshoot

Comment: This is still really unfortunate from a syntax and best-practices perspective. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) re: why commands shouldn't be stored in strings, and [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [the pertinent POSIX standards re: variable names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) -- all-caps names are reserved for variables with meaning to POSIX-specified tools, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are guaranteed safe for application use.

Comment: If you want to shorten things, define a function: `sftp_connection() { sftp -oIdentityFile=/home/account_xxx/.ssh/service_ssh user@host "$@"; }`, and then call `sftp_connection rm "$file"`

Answer (score 0):

Use a different client. `lftp` supports sftp as a transport, and has a subcommand for mirroring which will do the work of listing the remote directory and iterating over files for you.

Assuming your `~/.ssh/config` contains an entry like:

```
Host myhost
    IdentityFile /home/account_xxx/.ssh/service_ssh
```

...you can run:

```
lftp -e 'mirror -R fromvan/test/data/test_1 /tmp/test/data' sftp://user@myhost
```

Comment: Original answer didn't tell lftp to use the sftp transport. That's a rather critical piece -- be sure you note the edit.