# How to connect with SFTP server for automated shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sftp

I m trying to connect to SFTP server to fetch the data files regularly using automated shell script. I connect to the server as

`user@$server`
where it asks for password and I enter the password then I can run regular SFTP commands `get` and `mget` to fetch files.

The concern is that I have to provide password manually and it opens interactive shell. How can I run all these in just one command or without manual intervention.?

Although [How to run the sftp command with a password from Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386482/how-to-run-the-sftp-command-with-a-password-from-bash-script) answers little bit, I don't have privileges to install additional commandline utilities on my server.

I was wondering if there is any other way to solve this issue.

Comment: If you can set up public key trust, consider scp instead of sftp. It can be pretty easily included in a simple script. sftp is intended for interactive use.

Comment: Try [`lftp`](https://lftp.yar.ru/). It can easily be scripted.

Comment: I'm not sure how scp can be used!

Comment: Our system doesn't have lftp installed on the server. It 's hadoop system where we need to load sftp files from another client.

Comment: Set up a key pair for automated, passwordless login. It's fast, simple, easy and secure. Trying to send a password is none of those.

Comment: `scp /local/path/to/file user@remoteMachine(orIP):/sameOrDiff/remote/path/to` and many `cp` similar usages are possible. Good luck.

Comment: I think the most secure method would be using keypairs as has been suggested. Google RSA keys. As for expect; you will have to store your password in plaintext - which would not be recommended. Most remote access tools do not include auto password entry for this very reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [expect](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/201) command:

```
  #!/usr/bin/expect -c "
  spawn sftp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <USER>@<SERVER>
  expect \"*?assword:\"

  send \"<PASSWORD>\r\"
  expect \"sftp>\"

  #more commands

  #exit sftp when you're done
  send \"exit\r\"
  expect -exact \"$\"
  "
```

It'll enter the password without manual intervention.

`UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` will disable the host key checking and `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` will disable strict host key checking.

You can add that example in the `#more commands` section:

```
  #Example with get (from remote to local)
  send \"get <remotefilepath> <localfilepath>\r\"
  expect \"sftp>\"
```

Comment: It says `line 2: spawn: command not found` and ` bunch of other errors! Probably you missed sftp before <USER>@<PASSWORD>??? I believe these commands are blocked because I can open the man pages for those commands but it says command not found.

Comment: The shebang in `#!/usr/bin/expect` is telling what interpreter shall it be run with. I guess you're using `sh` and the script can't combine 2 interpreters. Try without the shebang:  `/usr/bin/expect`

Comment: Yeah I tried with `expect get_file.sh`, but it says `invalid command name "<USER>@<PASSWORD>"`. Do they have to be like this only? or `sftp <USER>@<PASSWORD>`?

Comment: Just to make sure with you: when I write something between `<>`, you have to replace it by something. For example, in this case `<USER>@<SERVER>` = `user@your_server_ip_or_remote_hostname`. In this case, you'll open a sftp session in the remote server as user. For `<PASSWORD>`, you need to replace it by the password required to have access to the remote server.

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear I can edit my answer to make it clearer

Comment: Also, `<USER>@<SERVER>` needs to be on the same line as  `StrickHostKeyChecking=no`