# Reading file opened with Python Paramiko SFTPClient.open method is slow

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko, netcdf

I am trying to remote read a netcdf file.
I used Paramiko package to read my file, like this:

```
import paramiko
from netCDF4 import Dataset

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=’hostname’, username=’usrname’, password=’mypassword’)

sftp_client = client.open_sftp()
ncfile = sftp_client.open('mynetCDFfile')
b_ncfile = ncfile.read()    # ****

nc = Dataset('test.nc', memory=b_ncfile)
```

But the run speed of `ncfile.read()` is VERY SLOW.

So my question is: Is there any alternative way to read a netcdf file remotely, or is there any approach to speed up `paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile.read()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Calling [`SFTPFile.prefetch`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile.prefetch) should increase the read speed:

```
ncfile = sftp_client.open('mynetCDFfile')
ncfile.prefetch()
b_ncfile = ncfile.read()
```

---

Another option is enabling read buffering, using `bufsize` parameter of [`SFTPClient.open`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.open):

```
ncfile = sftp_client.open('mynetCDFfile', bufsize=32768)
b_ncfile = ncfile.read()
```

(`32768` is a value of `SFTPFile.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE`)

Similarly for writes/uploads:
[Writing to a file on SFTP server opened using Paramiko/pysftp "open" method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58111798/850848).

---

Yet another option is to explicitly specify the amount of data to read (it makes [`BufferedFile.read`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/file.html#paramiko.file.BufferedFile.read) take a more efficient code path):

```
ncfile = sftp_client.open('mynetCDFfile')
b_ncfile = ncfile.read(ncfile.stat().st_size)
```

---

If none of that works, you can download the whole file to memory instead:
[Use pdfplumber and Paramiko to read a PDF file from an SFTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62052090/850848)

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` this way – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you