# Upload files to Box directly from SFTP server without saving an intermediate file using Python

Tags: python, file-upload, sftp, paramiko

```py
sftp.get(remotepath, localpath) #for sftp to localdrive
upload = client.folder(Folder_id).upload(localpath) #localdrive to box
```

Using Python I'm downloading files from SFTP server to local drive and then from local drive to my box.

Is that possible to upload my files to box directly from SFTP server using Python without saving the file to local drive?

I'm using Paramiko and [Box SDK](https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk/blob/master/docs/usage/files.md).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SFTPClient.open`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.open) to open a file on an SFTP server as if it were a local file. It returns a file-like object. You can then use the object with [`Folder.upload_stream`](https://box-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boxsdk.object.html#boxsdk.object.folder.Folder.upload_stream):

```
with sftp.open(remotepath, "rb") as flo:
    flo.prefetch()
    client.folder(folder_id).upload_stream(flo, file_name)
```

*For the `SFTPFile.prefetch` call, refer to:

[Reading file opened with Python Paramiko SFTPClient.open method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58433996/850848)*