# SFTP to S3 AWS Lambda using Python Paramiko is extremely slow

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, paramiko

I am using Paramiko library to stream data from SFTP to an S3 bucket with a python 3.8 lambda in AWS. The script is standard, downloading whole files smaller than 6MB, and for larger files doing multi chunk uploads with a chunk size of roughly 6 MB. However,  but I've noticed that the speed is very slow, about 200KB/sec for a ~47MB file, where based online this should at least be 2MB/sec(which is still considered fairly slow). There will not be many files over 1GB but the 15 minute lambda timeout will be reached at this rate with a 200MB file. I am using a VPC but I am not familiar with the configuration and we have a team that works with that. Is there a reason this is so incredibly slow?

Script:

```
    def open_ftp_connection(self): 
      """
      Opens ftp connection and returns connection object
      """
      client = paramiko.SSHClient()
      client.load_system_host_keys() 
      try: 
        transport = paramiko.Transport(self.host_name,22) 
        #self.trans = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
        transport.window_size = 134217727
        transport.use_compression()

        print("A")
      except Exception as e: 
        return 'conn_error' 
      try: 
        transport.connect(username=self.ftp_username, password=self.ftp_password)
        print("B")
        #transport.exec_command("ls")
        print("C")
        
      except Exception as identifier: 
        return 'auth_error' 
      ftp_connection = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport) 
      print("D")
      return ftp_connection        
    def transfer_chunk_from_ftp_to_s3(self,ftp_file,s3_connection,multipart_upload,bucket_name,ftp_file_path,s3_file_path, part_number,chunk_size):
        start_time = time.time()
        chunk = ftp_file.read(int(chunk_size))
        part = s3_connection.upload_part(Bucket=bucket_name,
            Key=s3_file_path, PartNumber=part_number, UploadId=multipart_upload["UploadId"],Body=chunk)
        end_time = time.time()
        total_seconds = end_time - start_time
        print(
            "speed is {} kb/s total seconds taken {}".format(
                math.ceil((int(chunk_size) / 1024) / total_seconds), total_seconds
            )
        )
        part_output = {"PartNumber": part_number, "ETag": part["ETag"]}
        return part_output
    

    def transfer_file_from_ftp_to_s3(self,
        bucket_name, ftp_file_path, s3_file_path, ftp_username, ftp_password, chunk_size,ftp_connection):
      #  ftp_connection = self.open_ftp_connection(
       #     FTP_HOST, ftp_username, ftp_password
      #  )
        ftp_file = ftp_connection.file(ftp_file_path, "r")
        s3_connection = boto3.client("s3")
        ftp_file_size = ftp_file._get_size()
        try:
            s3_file = s3_connection.head_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_file_path)
            if s3_file["ContentLength"] == ftp_file_size:
                print("File Already Exists in S3 bucket")
                ftp_file.close()
                return
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        logger.info("file size: "+str(ftp_file_size))
        logger.info("chunk size: "+str(chunk_size))
        if ftp_file_size <= int(chunk_size):
            # upload file in one go
            print("Transferring complete File from FTP to S3...")
            ftp_file_data = ftp_file.read()
            ftp_file_data_bytes = io.BytesIO(ftp_file_data)
            s3_connection.upload_fileobj(ftp_file_data_bytes, bucket_name, s3_file_path)
            
            print("Successfully Transferred file from FTP to S3!")
            ftp_file.close()
    
        else:
            print("Transferring File from FTP to S3 in chunks...")
            # upload file in chunks
            chunk_count = int(math.ceil(ftp_file_size / float(chunk_size)))
            multipart_upload = s3_connection.create_multipart_upload(
                Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_file_path
            )
            logger.info("chunk count: "+str(chunk_count))
            parts = []
            for i in range(chunk_count):
                print("Transferring chunk {}...".format(i + 1))
                part = self.transfer_chunk_from_ftp_to_s3(
                    ftp_file,
                    s3_connection,
                    multipart_upload,
                    bucket_name,
                    ftp_file_path,
                    s3_file_path,
                    i + 1,
                    chunk_size
                )
                parts.append(part)
                print("Chunk {} Transferred Successfully!".format(i + 1))
    
            part_info = {"Parts": parts}
            s3_connection.complete_multipart_upload(
                Bucket=bucket_name,
                Key=s3_file_path,
                UploadId=multipart_upload["UploadId"],
                MultipartUpload=part_info,
            )
            print("All chunks Transferred to S3 bucket! File Transfer successful!")
            ftp_file.close()
```

The code above is all called by this:

```
self.transfer_file_from_ftp_to_s3(self.s3_bucket,self.ftp_full_file_path, s3_file_path, self.ftp_username, self.ftp_password, CHUNK_SIZE,ftp_connection)
```

And here is the output:

```
speed is 222 kb/s total seconds taken 27.759796857833862
Chunk 1 Transferred Successfully!
Transferring chunk 2...
speed is 214 kb/s total seconds taken 28.721262216567993
Chunk 2 Transferred Successfully!
Transferring chunk 3...
speed is 193 kb/s total seconds taken 31.968283653259277
Chunk 3 Transferred Successfully!
Transferring chunk 4...
speed is 196 kb/s total seconds taken 31.360466480255127
Chunk 4 Transferred Successfully!
Transferring chunk 5...
speed is 216 kb/s total seconds taken 28.545111417770386
Chunk 5 Transferred Successfully!
Transferring chunk 6...
speed is 218 kb/s total seconds taken 28.293278217315674
Chunk 6 Transferred Successfully!
Transferring chunk 7...
speed is 217 kb/s total seconds taken 28.43106746673584
Chunk 7 Transferred Successfully!
Transferring chunk 8...
speed is 200 kb/s total seconds taken 30.775285482406616
Chunk 8 Transferred Successfully!
All chunks Transferred to S3 bucket! File Transfer successful!
```

edit:

adding ftp_file.prefetch() in the transfer_file_to_S3 function seemed to dramatically increase speed for the ~47MB file from 202KB to 2MB a second. However, for a 1GB file using the same chunk size, it starts out using 2MB a second, but by chunk 10, the speed decreases back to 202KB a second.

Comment: What's the bandwidth of the connection that you're reading from? Have you tried downloading similar-size files onto an EC2 instance?

Comment: Just a side comment... Rather than using your own SFTP server, you can use [AWS Transfer for SFTP](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/aws-transfer-for-sftp-fully-managed-sftp-for-s3/) to host an SFTP site that automatically stores files in S3.

Comment: @Parsifal Downloading on an EC2 instance, the speed is more like 2.5MB/sec to 3.5MB/sec.  I also tried downloading the file as a whole with lambda rather than using the chunk approach, and it still took roughly 4 minutes,

Comment: Is this just a VPC limitation?

Comment: See [Reading file opened with Python Paramiko SFTPClient.open method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58433996/850848).

Comment: I already am explicitly stating how much data to read in the file.read function. I added prefetch but it shaved off a few seconds, no major difference

Comment: So how large is your chunk size? + How fast is a download from SFTP to a local file and an upload from local file to S3?

Comment: That's all in the description, using 6MB as a chunk, and downloading on EC2 was 2.5 to 3.5MB a sec, which is more like the speed I am shooting for

Comment: I see only unclear "Downloading on an EC2 instance, the speed is more like 2.5MB/sec to 3.5MB/sec." I'm asking, how would your current code, modified to first download to a local file and then upload from the local file, perform. Including an example of such modified code.

Comment: AWS lambda has a size restriction of like 400MB or 500MB in tmp directory I believe, and from what I understand you cant download parts of a file over SFTP to local, so that wont work for 1GB files

Comment: I was not suggesting it to be the final solution/workaround. I've asked you for a *test* to narrow down the problem + SFTP *can* download parts of a file anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to the problem to use paramiko readv(), which reads a list of chunks and saves time because it doesn't use seek. I also added multithreading with the method above to download several chunks at once, then use the multipart upload. Doing readv alone sped it up to 2-3MB a sec, with higher speeds hitting 10MB a sec, and the multiple threads provided the same speeds, but processed different parts of the file simultaneously. This allowed a 1GB file to be read in less than 6 minutes, whereas the original would've only allowed a 200MB in a 15 minute timeframe. I'll also add prefetch and the other fixes mentioned in the comments were not used, as readv uses prefetch on its own, and prefetch doesnt help with large files