# Reading large Parquet file from SFTP with Pyspark is slow

Tags: python, pyspark, sftp, parquet

I'm having some issue reading data (parquet) from a SFTP server with SQLContext.

The Parquet file is quite large (6M rows). 
I found some solutions to read it, but it's taking almost 1hour..

Below is the script that works but too slow.

```
import pyarrow as pa  
import pyarrow.parquet as pq 
from fsspec.implementations.sftp import SFTPFileSystem
  
fs = SFTPFileSystem(host = SERVER_SFTP, port = SERVER_PORT, username = USER, password = PWD)

df = pq.read_table(SERVER_LOCATION\FILE.parquet, filesystem = fs)
```

When the data is not in some sftp server, I use the below code, which usually works well even with large file. So How can I use SparkSQL to read a remote file in SFTP?

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('PATH/file')
```

Things that I tried: using SFTP library to open but seems to loose all the advantage of SparkSQL.

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet(sftp.open('PATH/file'))
```

I also tried to use spark-sftp library, following this article without success: https://www.jitsejan.com/sftp-with-spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the `buffer_size` parameter in the pyarrow.parquet library, the computational time went from 51 to 21 minutes :)

```
df = pq.read_table(SERVER_LOCATION\FILE.parquet, filesystem = fs, buffer_size = 32768)
```

Thanks @Martin Prikryl for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

The fsspec uses Paramiko under the hood. And this is known problem with Paramiko:
[Reading file opened with Python Paramiko SFTPClient.open method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58433996/850848)

In fsspec, it does not seem to be possible to change the buffer size.

But you can derive your own implementation from `SFTPFileSystem` that does:

```
def BufferedSFTPFileSystem(SFTPFileSystem):
    def open(self, path, mode='rb'):
        return super().open(self, path, mode, bufsize=32768)
```