# Include password in SFTP batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, sftp

I need to connect to our SFTP server using the built in Windows `sftp` feature and a .bat file which automatically inputs the login data, user and password. I´ve tried everything and just cant figure out the correct way. No matter what I try, it always asks me to manually put in my password. I want to avoid that. It should do the whole SFTP process by itself once it runs.

One thing I tried was this:

```
sftp sftp://USERXYZ:PASSWORDXYZ@myftp.COMPANY.com
```

But this still asks me to manually put in my password and to make it worse, it thinks the user is `USERXYZ:PASSWORDXYZ` instead of just `USERXYZ`

Here's my script with dummy values:

```
sftp sftp://USER@myftp.COMPANY.com
lcd C:\Users\PATHXYZ
cd PATHXYZ
put TESTFILE.txt
bye
```

Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not allowed... and for good reason, Security. If you ran the password from command line, the password would be accessible if you interrogate the running services/processes.

Answer (score 3):

OpenSSH `sftp` does not have an option to provide a password for security reasons. It does not even accept an `sftp://` URL.

There are lot of workarounds and hacks used for Linux version:
[How to run the sftp command with a password from Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5386482/850848)
I'm not sure if there's a commonly used workaround/hack for Windows version.

Though you should not use a workaround/hack. It is better to use a public key authentication instead of a password authentication.
See [How to properly configure Win32-OpenSSH authentication](https://superuser.com/q/1041957/213663).

---

Or use another SFTP client that offers an option to provide a password. For example *(my)* [WinSCP client](https://winscp.net/) accepts the `sftp://` URL which you have tried to use.
There is a guide for converting [OpenSSH `sftp` script to WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_psftp_script_to_winscp).

Comment: Correct! Windows 10 comes with OpenSSH built in, so with some knowledge you can setup ssh keys for sftp only.