# Why heredoc does not work for sftp password?

Tags: bash, sftp, io-redirection, heredoc

I want to input the password to sftp using heredoc:

```
sftp root@example.com <<EOF
password
EOF
```

But it does not work. sftp still asks me to type password. I know I can use sshpass to input the password, but why cannot I just use the heredoc to input the password. I think heredoc will be read as the standard input for sftp. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It's not about heredoc. `sftp` does not accept the password using the stdin at all. This won't work either: `echo password|sftp user@example.com`. There are zillion questions here already that cover this. How example: [How to run the sftp command with a password from Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5386482/850848)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sftp` will read the password from `/dev/tty` or some other program when running under graphical environment. When you run `sftp` from the terminal, stdin is `/dev/tty`. The heredoc replaces stdin, but `sftp` will always read `/dev/tty` for password.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `sshpass`:

```
SSHPASS='password' sshpass -e sftp root@example.com
```

From `man sshpass`:

> `-e`: The password is taken from the environment variable "SSHPASS".