# How to pass password for an SFTP command in shell script without expect, sshpass or any 3rd party SFTP client

Tags: shell, sftp

I am connecting from a UNIX server to a third party server (EFT on client side).
EFT supports only dual authentication.

So client has provided us the userid and password and we have shared the public key to them.
My shell script has to push and pull the files from third party.
I don't have `expect`, `lftp`, `curl`, `sshpass` in my server, cannot install then either.
How do I pass the password for the `sftp` command in the shell script to connect to remote server?
Now I am keying the password manually for the file transfer to happen, which is working.
But need to automate this.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need a password authentication (in addition to the public key authentication), you cannot use vanilla OpenSSH `ssh`. It is purposefully built in a way *not to allow automating password authentication*.

- Either you need to hack the password input for `ssh` using tools like `expect` and `sshpass`:
  [Automatically enter SSH password with script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12202587/850848)
  [How to run the sftp command with a password from Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5386482/850848)
  *(it seems that you know this);*
- Or use another SFTP client (it seems that you have none and you cannot install any);
- That basically leaves you with implementing something. Either you will have to implement `expect`/`sshpass` equivalent. Or use your favourite programing language that is available on your server to implement the SFTP: Python/Perl/Ruby/PHP/C/C++. There are SFTP libraries for all of them.