# Switching from FTP to SFTP. Trying to find the SFTP options equivalent to ftp -vn

Tags: linux, unix, ftp, sftp

We're switching from using ftp to sftp.

I'm trying to find similar options using sftp as we had using ftp although they don't line up directly.

So the old ftp command uses -vn , So:

```
 ftp -vn ...
```

-v stands for verbose
-n stands for "Restrains ftp from attempting auto-login upon initial connection.

Unfortunately the options for sftp don't map directly to ftp so I'm trying to find the equivalent.

So for sftp I've found the following:
-N disables quiet mode (looks similar to -v; verbose used for FTP)

I can't really find an equivalent for the ftp option -n. If anyone has any suggestions. I'd appreciate it.

Also someone knows of a closer equivalent to ftp -v for use with sftp, if the -N option is not close enough please let me know.

Comment: This is XY problem. – See [How to run the sftp command with a password from Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5386482/850848)

Answer (score 1):

With `sftp` you will be asked for password every time you try to do login.

Of course if you have set ssh key make no sense to disable the keys as this may stop you from login in to the machine at all.

For verbose you can use `-v` few times to get more detailed debug output

At the end you can't expect two different programs to have the same options.