# Shell script stuck at entering password

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have been trying to execute a shell script with multiple approach but my script keeps getting stuck at the stage where it prompts to enter a password.

I have also tried to use Expect and Send the password but still not successful.

A very basic shell script I have is below

```sh
#!/bin/sh
mv text123.txt to test456.txt

sftp -P 2582 tuser@exemple.com

9874test---> This is the password 

cd route

put test456.txt 847c-43b2-8e50-0125n
```

The `put` command pastes the file to an account ID

The code renames the file then enters the connection details but gets stuck when its time to enter password.

Comment: Do you mean that you have put the password in the script?

Comment: Do you know how to use private and public keys to automatically identify (commonly used with SSH)?

Comment: Yes I am trying to pass the password from the shell script, I am trying to execute these commands from an external linux VM, From this external VM I need to connect to the SFTP server to make the file transfer. While connecting to the SFTP server I need to pass the password which I am unable to pass. I am new to shell and the use of linux not much aware of how to use Private and Public Keys.

Comment: I believe this thread will be able to help you out. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386482/how-to-run-the-sftp-command-with-a-password-from-bash-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386482/how-to-run-the-sftp-command-with-a-password-from-bash-script)